# Are these 2 expressions tautologies?

Tags: logic

1. (m=n)↔(n⊕(¬m))
2. (m≠n)↔(¬(n⊕(¬m))

Is it true? I can need functions that switch like these for my application. But I want to make sure I'm not yielding falsehood.

```
m  n   m=n   (n⊕(¬m))

0  0    1       1
1  0    0       0
1  1    1       1
0  1    0       0
```

Comment: What does the $\oplus$ symbol mean?

Comment: ⊕ means XOR (exclusive disjunction). Thanks

Comment: Why dont you write a truth table?

Comment: Please improve your title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to check is to substitute:

$$f(n,m) = n\oplus (\neg m) $$
$$f(0,0)= 0 \oplus 1 =1$$
$$f(0,1)= 0 \oplus 0 =0$$
$$f(1,0)= 1 \oplus 1 =0$$
$$f(1,1)= 1 \oplus 0 =1$$

so $f(n,m)\leftrightarrow(m=n)$ is true.
From this follows immediately that $\neg f(n,m)\leftrightarrow(m\ne n)$.